# Ocaml - apply a function to every string in a string list and returning a new string list

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

I'm a beginner at OCaml and I'm a bit confused on using match. For this problem, I'm learning to work with functions on string lists that return string lists. I'm trying to run a function that returns a bool on every element in a string list and get back as an output a string list of those bools. For example, say you have the following:

```
let foo str =
  (String.length str) > 3;;

let list1 = ["please";"help";"me"]
```

and you want to apply foo on every element in list1 with the following as the desired output:

`output = [ "true";"true";"false"]`

what I've done is obviously not working since I am not returning a string list:

```
let rec bar (ls : string list) : string list=
    match foo ls with
    | [] -> ()
    | x :: xs -> x :: bar xs
;;
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I could do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your match expression, both cases should be returning a list since that is the type you want as your result (not `()`), and you want to destructure the list (not the result of applying `foo` to the list) eg.

```
let rec bar (ls : string list) : string list=
    match ls with
    | [] -> []
    | x :: xs -> (if (foo x) then "true" else "false") :: bar xs
```